# Param value based to show data in Java POI

Tags: java, jsf, apache-poi

I am using JSF with apache poi.In **bundle.properties** I use **waitingMessage=Wait for {0}** bundle name can be used.
In JSF page below format display data.

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{userBundle.waitingMessage}" escape="false">
<f:param value="#{user.data}"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

My doubt is if the same bundle name used to POI XSSFRichTextString with param value is possible?

```
tableHeaderCell.setCellValue(new XSSFRichTextString(userBundle.getString('waitingMessage'));
```

Comment: Me too facing this issue. kindly help us.